# Is the usage of "so as to" correct?

Tags: word-usage, so-as-to

Can "so as to" be used, and if so in what contexts and in what situations? Can it be used formally and in written documents?

Edit: I'm looking more at an IT question for example "You can do 'something' so as to get the variable and process it"

Comment: It's in legal documents all the time...

Comment: Isolate X so as to enable Y to function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a very broad question, but to give you a couple of examples:

> He put on an elaborate ruse so as to deceive her.
>
> She tried to look nonplussed so as to conceal her rage.

Yes you can use that phrasing formally in writing or speech, although personally, I wouldn't. It has limited applications.

EDIT: Yes, based on your edit, you can use that terminology in IT:

> Ensure that the firewall is properly configured so as to prevent an attacker from infiltrating our network.

Comment: No I'm talking about Java(a programming language), so more like In better English: "get something from somewhere so that xyz can be done with it" or as I'm asking is this possible "Get abc so as to do xyz"

Comment: *Get abc so as to do xyz* Yes you can say that. You're using it similarly as I did meaning *to bring on,* *to bring about,* or *to cause.* In my sentence it means *to prevent,* but your usage is also correct.