# What's the meaning of 'so as' in 'so as to go past'?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, so-as-to

I am struggling with this sentence, I have googled it but am not satisfied.

I am not a native english speaker which is why I am facing this problem.

What is the meaning of the word 'so' and the words 'so as' in the following sentence.

"so as to go past".

Comment: The duplicate [Is the usage of 'so as to' correct?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/129570/is-the-usage-of-so-as-to-correct) was closed because of lack of reasonable research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression 'so as' can be used to express purpose, like 'in order to'.

> I am planning to move house so as to be closer to my place of work.
>
> OR
>
> I am planning to move house in order to be closer to my place of work.

[Englishgrammar.org](https://www.englishgrammar.org/order/)

Comment: I wonder why I was so severely downvoted?